# A surface with finite Euler Characteristic is conformally equivalent to a closed Riemann surface

Tags: riemann-surfaces, conformal-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I have been reading Choi-Schoen's '[The space of minimal embeddings of a surface into a three-dimensional manifold of positive Ricci curvature](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/da38/10780cef00a660fdbe822cd6adea21fe91b8.pdf)' and in the proof of proposition 1, they mentioned the following fact which I have difficulty with understanding. 
Let M be an orientable, minimal (which I don't think that we need for the questions I will ask) surface with smooth compact boundary and finite Euler characteristic then M is conformally a closed Riemann Surface with a finite number of disks and points are removed.

In [Meeks and Perez's monograph](http://www.ugr.es/~jperez/papers/monograph-book2.pdf)[p18] they explained a similar result for complete minimal surfaces by using the fact that the Gauss map is conformal.

I am confused with handling the boundary components of M. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are actually asking. "I'm confused" is not a question I can understand.

Comment: Basically, I am asking a proof of the claim in the paper.

Comment: This is a nontrivial result, which can be derived, for instance from the uniformization theorem, but you need some background on Fuchsian groups (say, S.Katok's book) in order to understand the proof. Let me know if you want to see one.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know about Fuchsian Groups. I found the book you mentioned. If you can sketch the proof may be I can try to fill the details out own my own. Thanks a lot.